# Calendar with used and availeble slots

Tags: postgresql

I'm building an medical appointment application, where doctors have predefined hour and day availability ranges and patients would be able to schedule appointments only in those ranges.

To model this, the system has three tables:

1. Turno (appointments in spanish).
2. Professionals (to register each doctor).
3. Agendas (to register the availability for each doctor).

Here's each table structure:

```
                                         Table "public.profesionals"
   Column    |              Type              | Collation | Nullable |                 Default                  
-------------+--------------------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------------
 id          | bigint                         |           | not null | nextval('profesionals_id_seq'::regclass)
 name        | character varying(255)         |           |          | 

                                            Table "public.agendas"
     Column     |              Type              | Collation | Nullable |                             Default                              
----------------+--------------------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------
 id             | bigint                         |           | not null | nextval('agendas_id_seq'::regclass)
 fechainicio    | date                           |           |          | 
 fechafin       | date                           |           |          | 
 horainicio     | time(0) without time zone      |           |          | 
 horafin        | time(0) without time zone      |           |          | 
 profesional_id | bigint                         |           |          | 

                                            Table "public.turnos"
     Column     |              Type              | Collation | Nullable |              Default               
----------------+--------------------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------
 id             | bigint                         |           | not null | nextval('turnos_id_seq'::regclass)
 patient_id     | bigint                         |           |          | 
 inserted_at    | timestamp(0) without time zone |           | not null | 
 updated_at     | timestamp(0) without time zone |           | not null | 
 horainicio     | time(0) without time zone      |           |          | 
 horafin        | time(0) without time zone      |           |          | 
 agenda_id      | bigint                         |           |          | 
 profesional_id | bigint                         |           |          |
```

And the sample data is here:

```
select id, name from profesionals;
 id |  name   
----+---------
  1 | Hernan
  2 | Marcelo
  3 | Carla
(3 rows)

select id, fechainicio, horainicio, fechafin, horafin, profesional_id from agendas;
 id | fechainicio | horainicio |  fechafin  | horafin  | profesional_id 
----+-------------+------------+------------+----------+----------------
  2 | 2022-05-02  | 11:30:00   | 2022-05-04 | 12:00:00 |              3
  3 | 2022-05-02  | 11:30:00   | 2022-05-04 | 12:00:00 |              2
  1 | 2022-05-02  | 10:00:00   | 2022-05-04 | 11:00:00 |              1

select id, patient_id, horainicio, horafin, agenda_id, profesional_id from turnos;
 id | patient_id | horainicio | horafin  | agenda_id | profesional_id 
----+------------+------------+----------+-----------+----------------
  1 |          1 | 10:00:00   | 12:00:00 |         1 |              1
  2 |          1 | 11:30:00   | 11:45:00 |         2 |              3
  3 |          1 | 12:00:00   | 12:30:00 |         3 |              2
(3 rows)
```

Now, I want to create a `cross tab` containing each doctor and each time frame, the cross between a doctor and a time frame could (or not) be available or used in an appointment.

So far I came up with this:

```sql
select * from crosstab(
        'with h as (
                        select
                                generate_series(
                                        ''2022-05-12 09:00:00''::timestamp,
                                        ''2022-05-12 12:00:00''::timestamp,
                                        ''30 min''::interval
                                )::time as hour
                )
                select
                        p.id::int as prof,
                        h.hour::text as attribute,
                        case
                          when h2.hour = h.hour then (
                              select json_agg(r) 
                              from (
                                 select t2.id 
                                 from turnos t2 
                                 where t2.id=t.id
                              ) r)::text
                        end::text as turno
                from turnos t
                join profesionals p on t.profesional_id = p.id
    join agendas aep on t.agenda_id = aep.id
                join h h2 on t.horainicio >= h2.hour and 
                    t.horainicio < (h2.hour + interval ''30 minutes'')
                cross join h
                group by 1, 2, 3
                order by 1, 2'
) as ct(
    "professional" int, 
    "09:00:00" text, 
    "09:30:00" text, 
    "10:00:00" text, 
    "10:30:00" text, 
    "11:00:00" text, 
    "11:30:00" text, 
    "12:00:00" text);
```

The query returns this:

```
 professional | 09:00:00 | 09:30:00 |  10:00:00  | 10:30:00 | 11:00:00 |  11:30:00  |  12:00:00  
--------------+----------+----------+------------+----------+----------+------------+------------
            1 |          |          | [{"id":1}] |          |          |            | 
            2 |          |          |            |          |          |            | [{"id":3}]
            3 |          |          |            |          |          | [{"id":2}] | 
(3 rows)
```

*Note: The inner json array contains each appointment. This allows me to click on each cell and then retrieve its contents.*

Now what's missing here, and I don´t figure out how to include is the availability.

Let's remember the agenda for each doctor:

```
 id | fechainicio | horainicio |  fechafin  | horafin  | profesional_id 
----+-------------+------------+------------+----------+----------------
  2 | 2022-05-02  | 11:30:00   | 2022-05-04 | 12:00:00 |              3
  3 | 2022-05-02  | 11:30:00   | 2022-05-04 | 12:00:00 |              2
  1 | 2022-05-02  | 10:00:00   | 2022-05-04 | 11:00:00 |              1
```

As you can see, `profesional_id=1` is available from `10:00:00` to `11:00:00`, `profesional_id=2` from `11:30:00` to `12:00:00` and `profesional_id=3` from `11:30:00` to `12:00:00`.

The visual result I want get is this:

```
 professional | 09:00:00 | 09:30:00 |  10:00:00  | 10:30:00 | 11:00:00 |  11:30:00  |  12:00:00  
--------------+----------+----------+------------+----------+----------+------------+------------
            1 |          |          | [{"id":1}] | AVAILABLE| AVAILABLE|            | 
            2 |          |          |            |          |          | AVAILABLE  | [{"id":3}]
            3 |          |          |            |          |          | [{"id":2}] | AVAILABLE 
(3 rows)
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Advice before you go any further: Use a range type. This makes your life so much easier when working with planning and agendas. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html

Comment: @FrankHeikens, indeed, I forgot those, thanks for the tip.